# Wrap text after a specified amount of characters in a JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, awt

Given a JTextPane, how can it be configured so that it wraps its text when:

1. It reaches its component boundaries (functionality already provided by Swing)
2. *or* when it reaches a certain character limit per line (e.g. 80)

In other words:
It should always wrap at max. 80 characters, unless it needs to wrap earlier due to space constraints.

Comment: That functionality is easily accomplished by a [JTextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTextArea.html).  Do you need the functionality of a JTextPane?  Do you need multiple fonts and/or embedded images/objects?

Comment: @VGR I use a JTextPane so that I can configure the line spacing. I wasn't able to figure out how to do that in a JTextArea.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do something like this by using a custom *WrapEditorKit* class and applying it with the **[JTextPane#setEditorKit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#setEditorKit-javax.swing.text.EditorKit-)** method, for example:

```
jTextPane1.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
```

Now, this *WrapEditorKit* class can be found all over the internet but I'm not really sure who the original author actually might be. [Here is one place you can find it](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTextPane/Wrap_long_words_in_JTextPane.htm) or, in the below code of course.

After the *WrapEditorKit* has been applied, we can then manipulate the Right Margin Inset value of the **JTextPane** using a  **[ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/componentlistener.html)** for that very same **JTextPane** so to limit the number of columns (characters) allowable per displayed line, even when the text pane is resized.

Below is a runnable code which basically demonstrates how this can be done. Be sure to read the comments in code:

[image]

```
public class JTextPanelWrapAtColumnDemo {
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
    
    private javax.swing.JFrame frame;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jsp;
    private javax.swing.JTextPane jtp;
    
    /* The max number of characters we want in the JTextPane 
       before a wrap is carried out. Can be optionally set in
       the Constructor of this class or the getter method:
       'setCharacterColumns()'.            */
    private int characterColumns = 80;
    
    /* An offset value to tweak the characterColumns value
       for different fonts since fonts other than monospaced
       fonts contain different character widths. Can be 
       optionally set in the Constructor of this class or 
       the getter method: 'setOffset()'.     */
    private int offset = 2;
    
    
    /* Constructor - Optionally accepts arguments for 
       'characterColumns' and 'offset' (in that order.
       null can be supplied for any argument if default
       for whatever respective variable is desired:  */
    public JTextPanelWrapAtColumnDemo(Integer... charColumnsAndOrOffset) {
        // Deal with Constructor arguments (if any):
        if (charColumnsAndOrOffset.length > 0) {
            if (charColumnsAndOrOffset[0] != null) {
                this.characterColumns = charColumnsAndOrOffset[0];
            }
            
            if (charColumnsAndOrOffset.length > 1 && charColumnsAndOrOffset[1] != null) {
                this.offset = charColumnsAndOrOffset[1];
            }
        }
        
        // Create Form:
        initForm();
        
        /* Set font to Monospaced since with most fonts, each character 
           can be a different width. With Monospaced, all characters 
           are the same width. For demonstation purposes, a MonoSpaced 
           font will provide a better display example. This of course 
           is optional. You can play with the 'charsPerLine' variable 
           value to acquire your desired effect. This variable is located 
           within the ComponentListener's 'componentResize()' method:  */
        jtp.setFont(new java.awt.Font(java.awt.Font.MONOSPACED, java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 12));
        
        // Setup for text wrapping with a custom WrapEditorKit class:
        jtp.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
        
        
        
        /* Add a ComponentListener to JTextPane. This is required so that 
           we always know when the JTextPane is resized and we can update
           the right margin setting accordingly:        */
        jtp.addComponentListener(new java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent e) {
                // Get metrics from the graphics of your JTextPane:
                java.awt.FontMetrics metrics = jtp.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(jtp.getFont());
                
                /* Get the height of a line of text in this font and 
                   render context. Not really required for this example
                   but it's good to know.      */
                int stringHeight = metrics.getHeight();
                
                /* Get the Width of a line of text in this font and render 
                   context. We need this value.       */
                /* Creating a sample String - Totally font dependent
                   but, the uppercase letter 'W' is used in the String.join()
                   method because it is typically the widest character 
                   in a font. You can use the String.repeat() for newer 
                   Java JDK's. */
                int stringWidth = metrics.stringWidth(
                        String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(characterColumns + offset, "W")));
                
                /* Set the JTextPane's Margins:
                   ===========================              */
                /* Determine what we'll need for a Right Margin. This will 
                   ultimately ensure the text will go no further than our 
                   set 'characterColumns' value (default is 80):     */
                int rightMarginLength = jtp.getWidth() - stringWidth;
                if (jtp.getWidth() < stringWidth) {
                    rightMarginLength = 0;
                }
                
                // Get the current JTextPane margin insets
                java.awt.Insets ins = jtp.getMargin();
                
                /* Set the Right Margin of the JTextPane but keep the originl
                   Top, Left, and Bottom margins as they are:        */
                 jtp.setMargin(new java.awt.Insets(ins.top, ins.left, ins.bottom, rightMarginLength));
            }

            @Override
            public void componentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent e) {
                // Do Nothing...
            }
        });
        
        /* Some demo text for JTextPane to start with (optional of course).
           You will notice that as soon as the form is resized widthwise even 
           the slightest bit, the text will wrap.        */
        jtp.setText("123456789-123456789-123456789-123456789-1234567890-123456789-"
                + "123456789-123456789-1234567890-123456789-123456789-123456789-"
                + ls + ls + "This Is Some Demo Text With Monospaced Font. Wrap Is "
                + "Set At Approximately " + characterColumns + " Characters. This "
                + "Is Yet Some More Demo Text. And This Is Some Demo Text And "
                + "Yet Again, More Demo Text.");

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    private void initForm() {
        frame = new javax.swing.JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("JTextPane - 'Wrap After " + characterColumns + "th Column' Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(595, 400));
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        
        jtp = new javax.swing.JTextPane();
        
        
        // A JScrollPane for the JTextPane:
        jsp = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jsp.setViewportView(jtp);
        jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(javax.swing.JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        frame.getContentPane().add(jsp, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    // Getters & Setters:

    public int getCharacterColumns() {
        return characterColumns;
    }

    public void setCharacterColumns(int characterColumns) {
        this.characterColumns = characterColumns;
    }

    public int getOffset() {
        return offset;
    }

    public void setOffset(int offset) {
        this.offset = offset;
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JTextPanelWrapAtColumnDemo(80, null).startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            frame.setVisible(true);
            
        });
        
    }
    
    /* The 'WrapEditorKit' Class (and related classes):
       ================================================
    
       You can get these classes here:
       http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Swing_How_to/JTextPane/Wrap_long_words_in_JTextPane.htm
    */
    class WrapEditorKit extends javax.swing.text.StyledEditorKit {

        javax.swing.text.ViewFactory defaultFactory = new WrapColumnFactory();

        @Override
        public javax.swing.text.ViewFactory getViewFactory() {
            return defaultFactory;
        }

    }

    class WrapColumnFactory implements javax.swing.text.ViewFactory {

        @Override
        public javax.swing.text.View create(javax.swing.text.Element elem) {
            String kind = elem.getName();
            if (kind != null) {
                switch (kind) {
                    case javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.ContentElementName:
                        return new WrapLabelView(elem);
                    case javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName:
                        return new javax.swing.text.ParagraphView(elem);
                    case javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.SectionElementName:
                        return new javax.swing.text.BoxView(elem, javax.swing.text.View.Y_AXIS);
                    case javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.ComponentElementName:
                        return new javax.swing.text.ComponentView(elem);
                    case javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.IconElementName:
                        return new javax.swing.text.IconView(elem);
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }

            // default to text display
            return new javax.swing.text.LabelView(elem);
        }
    }

    class WrapLabelView extends javax.swing.text.LabelView {

        public WrapLabelView(javax.swing.text.Element elem) {
            super(elem);
        }

        @Override
        public float getMinimumSpan(int axis) {
            switch (axis) {
                case javax.swing.text.View.X_AXIS:
                    return 0;
                case javax.swing.text.View.Y_AXIS:
                    return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using String.join and Collections.nCopies, you can just use [String.repeat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)).  As in, `"W".repeat(characterColumns + offset)`.  If you’re going to provide a custom ViewFactory, wouldn’t it be easier to just make a regular JTextArea and customize its ViewFactory to return Views with larger [bottom insets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/text/CompositeView.html#getBottomInset())?

Comment: Indeed - **1**) "use [String#repeat()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int))", is mentioned in code comments. This demo was coded in Java8 where String#repeat() is not available.  **2**) "wouldn’t it be easier to just make a regular JTextArea", it certainly would and would be a little lighter overall but, the OP specified a **JTextPane**. Most likely due to [its capabilities over a **JTextArea**](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/web-applications/difference-between-jtextpane-and-jtextarea/).

Comment: Right, but tyrondis appears to only want a JTextArea with a different line spacing.  So a JTextArea with a modified ViewFactory might suffice.  And it would be a shorter and cleaner solution.